# Where is my iMac A1419 SSD?

Tags: imac, ssd, upgrade

I’m trying to upgrade my iMac A1419 (late 2013 iMac14,2) model SSD from 256 Gb to 2 Tb. I watched a lot of videos how to do it, but when I opened my iMac I found the place where usually the HDD is located empty! Where is the SSD? Is it still possible to upgrade with 2.5" SSD drive?

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid the model number on Macs isn't all that much use in identification. A1419 covers iMacs from 2012 to 2017 - 5 major model revisions. We need to know its 'designation' eg, "Mid 2017" or Late 2013" to know better the internal design.

Comment: I bought it in 2014, so most probably its late 2013… its iMac 14,2

Comment: Ifixit shows an HD - https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+27-Inch+EMC+2639+Hard+Drive+Replacement/19643 step 21/22 but this model also came with an SSD option according to Everymac - https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-3.2-27-inch-aluminum-late-2013-specs.html idk where that would be, I've never taken one of these apart, sorry.

Comment: The SSD (if you find it) will likely be an Apple proprietary 12+16 pin, rather than a standard m2 or SATA, so sourcing a replacement may be tricky. TBH, I would just get a Thunderbolt (v1) or USB3 external SSD. You could still boot from the internal, but keep large libraries (photos, iTunes, etc) and files on the external.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Where is the SSD?

The PCIe SSD is located on the back side of the logic board above the USB and Thunderbolt ports. The red arrow in the image below points to the connector where the SSD would plug into. You need to remove the logical board to exchange the SSD. I good video showing the steps is given [here](https://eshop.macsales.com/installvideos/imac-27-inch-2013-pciessd/). I would post directly from the video, but the [video usage policy](https://eshop.macsales.com/service/terms) instructs not to.

### Is it still possible to upgrade with 2.5" SSD drive?

If the power and data connectors exists on the logic board, then the answer is yes. The green arrows in the images below point to the power connector where the SATA cable would plug into. The yellow arrow in the image below points to the data connector where the SATA cable would plug into.

Your model Mac can have a SATA drive and/or a PCIe drive installed. The SATA drive can be a HDD or SSD. The PCIe drive is a SSD, which would be faster than a SATA SDD or HDD. If you Mac does not have SATA drive, then there may not be a SATA cable and 3.5" drive mounting hardware included with your Mac. I do not see this cable or hardware in the image you posted.

[image]

The above image was taken from [this webpage](https://www.ebay.com/itm/184882742392?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-117182-37290-0&mkcid=2&itemid=184882742392&targetid=1263094004306&device=c&mktype=&googleloc=9019667&poi=&campaignid=14859008593&mkgroupid=130497710760&rlsatarget=pla-1263094004306&abcId=9300678&merchantid=6481894&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI-Ofuk_jw9AIVQwJMCh3zEQpfEAQYBCABEgKtX_D_BwE).

[image]

Currently, the SATA cable and 3.5" drive mounting hardware is available for purchase off the web in used (and perhaps new) condition. For example, [this website](https://www.ebay.com/itm/265287887395?_trkparms=amclksrc%3DITM%26aid%3D1110018%26algo%3DHOMESPLICE.COMPLISTINGS%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20210609144404%26meid%3Dc2ba4ce1a7004aa9a0f4d2c620727a09%26pid%3D101196%26rk%3D2%26rkt%3D12%26sd%3D275014720913%26itm%3D265287887395%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D0%26pg%3D2047675%26algv%3DItemStripV101HighAdFeeWithCompV3Ranker%26brand%3DApple&_trksid=p2047675.c101196.m2219&amdata=cksum%3A265287887395c2ba4ce1a7004aa9a0f4d2c620727a09%7Cenc%3AAQAGAAACAMpBSOsvFthpa4xmKXvXYjwQ7KOQO1DI4elzF6xcoVzOhcYagL8RAEj2EguX2xxI7CZQkWHXOxD6IQ4L7kAxqgiZ2henddI%252FvaVrpD68qg4HfJPFxtmsSSw%252Fm5biNt2T9HbJQaXTVgfqew6eDYJ9btgoWPaoEBbO%252FSuNrVcz7VTHS%252FQdMvXk6vxOOnopKLQgeJYpapbM2chD6ocIQmO5Vjas3o2f6g%252B32ON135Q6k8J%252BnjLJ1HjhpjBpojtDDcgkkvzyjLOX0HdY7fP6y%252FEDzBO27rpwo2xBCLmUHS7J%252BhRjyAvsZJ9jQmXB02pqxBvzTtDxigdccXVtXvBw60BxqtmUZq%252BAMx8nOCCl0D%252FKMgDEAU1WA2g9zCjT9ec4kyS1FGbQts8jn3GlyXFIeLF9YeL3lM6ZhdlqJq%252BLnhdB3UTccaw92uvUB2dK%252BJZZE37ey3KI3TskvexzBEv8IDiLud3TrcqA%252Bzan0%252FSEOmgb1Az1wPvgXcIBO2e%252BwoKcg9qzhJCOdN3AUt4P14jAUgs6OrrbrRbD3lYrWguV3lgpPiVnSGdHiVK4mq35NcgU1Eu93KX75FSOW2u4uMKP6yU%252FyUV4M0H1YTKuIXLn62ckw9UCu5WLwN45btNu%252BU5iYKOlc00BebPI5UmBHw6nM07UP1XN3p5waK5y3ZQGKdkV8o2d%7Campid%3APL_CLK%7Cclp%3A2047675) offers both the cable and hardware. Below is an image of the cable and hardware.

[image: cable and hardware]

To install a 2.5" SATA SSD, additional items will be required. Below is an example of what OWC offers. There are probably other suppliers that offer similar items. First, OWC offers a [NEWER TECHNOLOGY ADAPTADRIVE 2.5" to 3.5" Drive Converter Bracket](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/NewerTech/ADPTADRV/), which is shown below. You would mount the 2.5" SATA SSD in the bracket. According to OWC, this bracket will work both with OWC SSDs and SSDs from other manufacturers.

[image: converter]

Second, OWC offers a [In-line Digital Thermal Sensor for Hard Drive Upgrade for 27" Apple iMac Late 2012 to Mid 2019 Models](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/DIDIMACHDD12/), which is shown below. This plugs in between the SATA cable and the ADAPTADRIVE bracket. The thermal sensor is to be attached to the metal surface of the SSD by the included adhesive. According to OWC, this sensor will work both with OWC SSDs and SSDs from other manufacturers.

[image: sensor]

### Replacing the existing PCIe SSD versus adding a SATA SSD

Replacing the existing PCIe SSD with a 2 TB upgrade would cost more for the drive. However, PCIe drives are much faster than legacy SATA. [OWC](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/imac-27-inch/2013-2019) sells PCIe SSDs for your Mac which can replace your existing PCIe SSD without the need for purchasing addition parts. The table below compares the three 2 TB SSD models offered by [OWC](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/imac-27-inch/2013-2019) for your Mac.

| Model | Interface | Warrenty | Sequential Read | Sequential Write | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [OWC Aura Pro X2](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/S3DAPT4MA20K/) | NVMe – PCIe 3.1 x4 | 5 year | 3208 MB/s | 2432 MB/s | 409.00 USD† |
| [OWC Mercury Extreme Pro 6G](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/S3D7P6GS2.0/) | SATA 6.0 Gb/s | 5 year | 550 MB/s | 530 MB/s | 349.00 USD‡ |
| [OWC Mercury Electra 6G](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/S3D7E6GD20/) | SATA 6.0 Gb/s | 3 year | 540 MB/s | 500 MB/s | 244.00 USD‡ |

† Includes a complete upgrade kit with tools and adhesive.
‡ Drive only.

### References

- [iMac 27" A1419 HDD Hard Drive Caddy Housing Brackets Rails w/ Screws &SATA Cable](https://www.ebay.com/itm/265287887395?_trkparms=amclksrc%3DITM%26aid%3D1110018%26algo%3DHOMESPLICE.COMPLISTINGS%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20210609144404%26meid%3Dc2ba4ce1a7004aa9a0f4d2c620727a09%26pid%3D101196%26rk%3D2%26rkt%3D12%26sd%3D275014720913%26itm%3D265287887395%26pmt%3D1%26noa%3D0%26pg%3D2047675%26algv%3DItemStripV101HighAdFeeWithCompV3Ranker%26brand%3DApple&_trksid=p2047675.c101196.m2219&amdata=cksum%3A265287887395c2ba4ce1a7004aa9a0f4d2c620727a09%7Cenc%3AAQAGAAACAMpBSOsvFthpa4xmKXvXYjwQ7KOQO1DI4elzF6xcoVzOhcYagL8RAEj2EguX2xxI7CZQkWHXOxD6IQ4L7kAxqgiZ2henddI%252FvaVrpD68qg4HfJPFxtmsSSw%252Fm5biNt2T9HbJQaXTVgfqew6eDYJ9btgoWPaoEBbO%252FSuNrVcz7VTHS%252FQdMvXk6vxOOnopKLQgeJYpapbM2chD6ocIQmO5Vjas3o2f6g%252B32ON135Q6k8J%252BnjLJ1HjhpjBpojtDDcgkkvzyjLOX0HdY7fP6y%252FEDzBO27rpwo2xBCLmUHS7J%252BhRjyAvsZJ9jQmXB02pqxBvzTtDxigdccXVtXvBw60BxqtmUZq%252BAMx8nOCCl0D%252FKMgDEAU1WA2g9zCjT9ec4kyS1FGbQts8jn3GlyXFIeLF9YeL3lM6ZhdlqJq%252BLnhdB3UTccaw92uvUB2dK%252BJZZE37ey3KI3TskvexzBEv8IDiLud3TrcqA%252Bzan0%252FSEOmgb1Az1wPvgXcIBO2e%252BwoKcg9qzhJCOdN3AUt4P14jAUgs6OrrbrRbD3lYrWguV3lgpPiVnSGdHiVK4mq35NcgU1Eu93KX75FSOW2u4uMKP6yU%252FyUV4M0H1YTKuIXLn62ckw9UCu5WLwN45btNu%252BU5iYKOlc00BebPI5UmBHw6nM07UP1XN3p5waK5y3ZQGKdkV8o2d%7Campid%3APL_CLK%7Cclp%3A2047675)
- [NEWER TECHNOLOGY ADAPTADRIVE 2.5" to 3.5" Drive Converter Bracket](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/NewerTech/ADPTADRV/) (with video)
- [OWC Install Videos / iMac 27-inch (Late 2013) / HDD](https://eshop.macsales.com/installvideos/imac_27in5k_14late_hdd/iMac14-2/)
- [OWC Install Videos / iMac 27-inch (Late 2013) / PCIe SSD](https://eshop.macsales.com/installvideos/imac-27-inch-2013-pciessd/)
- [OWC DIY BUNDLE Complete Hard Drive Upgrade Kit for 27" Apple iMac 2012 and later Models](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/DIYIMACHDD12/) (with video)
- [OWC DIY BUNDLE In-line Digital Thermal Sensor for Hard Drive Upgrade for 27" Apple iMac Late 2012 to Mid 2019 Models](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/DIDIMACHDD12/) (with video)
- [OWC Solid State Drives For iMac 27-Inch (Late 2013 - 2019)](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/imac-27-inch/2013-2019)

Answer (score 0):

Hope my answer is not too late. I have a 2017 iMac A1418, with the exact same issue. So, pulled the Logic board out and replaced the PCIe card. Timetec 1TB for iMac, $122.45 from Amazon.
Also, while on Amazon, I added another 1TB hard drive HGST 2.5inch $43.95, Deal4Go HDD SATA data power cable SSD Hard Drive Cable Replacement $13.99. Everything plugs right in.
If you want the hard drive rubber pads, Ebay for about $9.00. But the drive fits in without the pads.
I have 2TB of space and I keep my PCIe as my system and application drive. Other drive as data only. Lightening fast this way.